# Programmatically Refreshing Environment Variable References in PATH (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, windows-10, environment

**Background**

I have a Python script that sets environment variables into the registry, then [broadcasts an update using the WinSDK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/104011/how-to-propagate-environment-variables-to-the-system) to tell the system a variable was updated. This behaves similar to setx and the manual Environment Variable UI. This works great in Windows 7.

However, in Windows 10, it *almost* works.

**Here is my issue**

1. I set an environment variable (XXX = c:\my_dir)
2. I then insert a reference to XXX into the PATH variable via the registry. I made sure to use the REG_EXPAND_SZ type.
3. I then broadcast the update.
4. When I restart a new cmd.exe shell, I can see my new variable XXX (echo %XXX%), however, the reference to XXX is not properly expanded when I view the PATH.
5. In order to get my path update to stick, I need to either manually go into the Environment Variables UI and "edit" the path, or I need to log in and log out.

The weird thing is that this only affects PATH. If I add my reference to another variable (PYTHONPATH, for example), everything seems to work as intended.

**What I've Tried**

- Killing the explorer.exe tasktree and restarting
- Sub-processing out to setx works, but I'd like to keep my implementation in pure python.

**Update Environment Code**

```
import ctypes

def update_environment():
    """Uses ctypes to send a message to all windows that the environment has
    been updated. This has the same effect as pressing the 'OK' button in the
    windows environment variables dialog.

    References:
        https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/104011"""
    wm_settingchange = 0x001A
    hwnd_broadcast = wintypes.HWND(0xffff)
    smto_abortifhung = 0x0002
    env_message = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer('Environment')
    result = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageTimeoutW(hwnd_broadcast,
                                                      wm_settingchange,
                                                      0,
                                                      env_message,
                                                      smto_abortifhung,
                                                      5000,
                                                      0)
    return result
```

**Question**

Are there any other known ways to force windows 10 to refresh the environment (specifically the environment references in PATH)?

Comment: It would be better to avoid the dependency on global `ctypes.windll.user32` to instead use `user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)`. (The global `windll` loader was a bad idea and never should have been added to ctypes.) Also, check `last_error = ctypes.get_last_error()` for errors such as `ERROR_TIMEOUT` if `result` is 0. You can handle the error locally or `raise ctypes.WinError(last_error)` to let the caller handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll mod the code with your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed around with a few things and found what (I think) is the issue.

Basically, every registry key I was setting was of type REG_EXPAND_SZ. In Windows 7, this seemed to work fine. However, this won't force a re-expansion of my variable in Windows 10 unless my XXX key is set to REG_SZ. If I do that, then windows will properly update the variable reference.

Comment: AFAIK it shouldn't work in Windows 7 either. The shell reloads the environment in 4 passes. First it loads the `REG_SZ` system values and then the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` system values that should depend only on `REG_SZ` system values. Next it loads the user's `REG_SZ` values and then the user's `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values that should depend only on system values and `REG_SZ` user values. Then the user `Path` gets appended to the system `Path`.

Comment: Color me confused - but yes, it has worked in Win7 on our production machines for years. Maybe a bug on Win7 when it *shoudn't* have worked?

Comment: I don't know. I'll try to check later when I have access to a Windows 7 machine.